# Is there a modification of django framework in the last 24 hours?

Tags: django

We experienced strange behaviour. Especially under chrome, some items are missing. Anyone ?

Comment: Sorry for the mispelling. It was "hours" instead of "jours" in the title

Comment: The problem is not the misspelling, but the total lack of information in your post. What "strange behaviour"? What "items are missing"? Why would you think it has anything to do with Django itself? Have you updated your Django version in the last 24 hours? Are you tracking the repo head? Why?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the lack of information. For example, many items in our admin interface under Chrome are missing (it works well in firefox). We haven' t udpated anything

Comment: If you haven't updated anything, how would changes to Django affect you?

Comment: As Bruno said,  "if your dependencies aren't pinned, you might have auto-updated". Does this speak to you Daniel ?

Comment: well that would only happen if you deployed your code and updated the dependencies, did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? You should always [pin the version you use](https://nvie.com/posts/pin-your-packages/), which means that once it's published, it will never change.

The code is open source, you can check yourself from [the github repository](https://github.com/django/django/commits/master) and there are other more appropriate channels than Stack Overflow, IMO:

- The [Django weblog](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/), where a post is published each time there is a new release.
- The [Django users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-users) mailing list/google group is another place where you can keep up to date.
- PyPI gives you [the release history](https://pypi.org/project/Django/#history).
- Finally, with any open source software, don't be afraid of digging into the source code and see what has changed. Github has a great way of comparing between 2 tags, for instance for the latest 2 1.11.x relases: https://github.com/django/django/compare/1.11.16...1.11.17

There was 2 new bugfix relases published [on each 2.1.x and 1.11.x branches](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2018/dec/03/bugfix-releases/) yesterday, so if your dependencies aren't pinned, you might have auto-updated, but without further details it's hard to tell you more.

Comment: Why are you mentionning DRF ??? The op is talking about Django, not DRF.

Comment: Wow, I miss a coffee I think, my brain inserted REST between Django and Framework... Thanks for that, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. We are investigating this lead and will come back soon.